Data Conversion in Python: Convert Lambert Conformal Conic to Latitude and Londitude
Is there a common method in Python to convert lambert conformal conic projection to latitude and longitude (I assume that it would be WGS84)? The horizontal coverage is Europe.
A plot of my data looks as follows:

I have read that I could use the package pyproj. Is that correct?
EDIT: print(data.latitude[0:20,0:20])
<xarray.DataArray 'latitude' (y: 20, x: 20)>
array([[20.292281, 20.306942, 20.32158 , ..., 20.538402, 20.552673, 20.56692 ],
       [20.333665, 20.348339, 20.36299 , ..., 20.580011, 20.594295, 20.608555],
       [20.375059, 20.389747, 20.404412, ..., 20.621631, 20.635928, 20.650201],
       ...,
       [20.997195, 21.012085, 21.026951, ..., 21.247169, 21.261664, 21.276135],
       [21.038751, 21.053655, 21.068535, ..., 21.288954, 21.303462, 21.317946],
       [21.080317, 21.095234, 21.110128, ..., 21.330749, 21.34527 , 21.359767]])
Coordinates:
    step           timedelta64[ns] ...
    isobaricInhPa  float64 ...
    latitude       (y, x) float64 20.29 20.31 20.32 20.34 ... 21.33 21.35 21.36
    longitude      (y, x) float64 -17.49 -17.44 -17.4 ... -17.03 -16.98 -16.94
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Attributes:
    units:          degrees_north
    standard_name:  latitude
    long_name:      latitude


Add sample data to your question so the community is able to help

@PepeNO how can I add data to Stackoverflow using Python?

Edit your question and paste as text a few rows of your data set to see how the data to reproject looks like.

@PepeNO, done!.

Those numbers look like coordinates already in CRS 4326 (lat long), what is the CRS code of your original data? And in which format comes your original data or how do you load it into a dataset?

A very simple way is using geopandas
import geopandas as gpd

data = gpd.read_file(file_points_4839) #file in LCC epsg:4839
data = data.to_crs(4326) #reproject to epsg:4326 lat/lon    

dataset sample
EPSG:4839
   id                        geometry
0   0    POINT (123205.19 132829.099)
1   1   POINT (-90012.735 307220.008)
2   2  POINT (-89809.331 -165438.654)
EPSG:4326
   id                   geometry
0   0  POINT (12.30286 52.18136)
1   1   POINT (9.13536 53.75516)
2   2    POINT (9.25934 49.5047)

